# Valgrind error possibly to do with malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am having problems  with my code. I am getting valgrind errors, which have to to with malloc. I am confused since I am not having any problems with the other parts of the code, which are exactly the same as the parts I am having problems with. The errors I am getting are:

```
==15151==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)                                                          
==15151==    by 0x4006E2: main (additup.c:28)




struct bigInt {
      int digit;
      struct bigInt *next;
      struct bigInt *prev;
};

struct bigInt* curInt;
struct bigInt* intHead;
struct bigInt* intTail;
struct bigInt* curSum;
struct bigInt* sumHead;
struct bigInt* sumTail;

int main(){
  int addSum(int i );
  curInt = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt));
  intHead = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt));
  intTail = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt));
  curSum = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt)); // Problem: line 28
  sumHead = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt)); //Problem: line 29
  sumTail = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt));  //Problem: line 30
  addSum(11); //add head to sum linked list
  addSum(99);//add tail to sum linked list
  addSum(0);

int addSum(int i){ //adds sum  structure to front of linked list
  struct bigInt* x = malloc(sizeof(struct bigInt));
  if(i==11){
    x->digit=i;
    sumHead=x;
    curSum=x;
  } else {
    x->next=sumHead->next;
    sumHead->next=x;
    x->prev=sumHead;
    curSum=x;
    x->digit=i; 
  if(i==99) sumTail=x;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks `

Comment: Use [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/); don't reinvent your own arbitrary precision library

Comment: The bug is probably in some code that you don't show, like `addSum`. Consider also compiling with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`  and perhaps even also with `-fsanitize=address`

Comment: just added addSum to the code so you can see it

Comment: Always clear the resulting zone from `malloc`. Or use `calloc` instead of `malloc` (with one single element for `calloc`)

Comment: BTW, we are not a debugging service.

Comment: I know you are not a debuggins system, I just dont understand what is wrong because lines 28,29,30 are exact duplicates of the 3 previous lines

Comment: The error is yours, not from `valgrind`

Comment: That's a strange place to declare addSum - top of main() ?

Comment: Owait - definition of addSum() is nested...

Comment: The body of main() is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: Umm.. this might seem like a silly thing to ask, but.. ..  does this compile?

Comment: Is this two lines all Valgrind tells you?

Comment: *Did* you ran this inside a debugger, stepping through the code inspecting the values of all relevant variables to learn what is really going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 addSum(99);//add tail to sum linked list
//...
  if(i==99) sumTail=x;
```

That's a memory leak. Previous malloc'd block pointed to by sumTail is no longer accessible. ... And the other two blocks get lost the same way.

Comment: so since I malloc the structures x, which will be pointed to in sumTail, curSum , and sumHead, I dont need to malloc  sumTail, curSum , and sumHead on their own?

Comment: Right. No need to malloc first if they're allocated again later. You could initialize to NULL. Or just copy the digit value over, maybe, instead of allocating another struct.

Comment: Great thank you. I just deleted the lines malloc-ing  sumTail, curSum , and sumHead and the errors disappeared